# How to get srcset from img tag using scrapy python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

So I'm extracting some info from product pages and I want to get the img link from the img tag but it has a srcset with multiple links and I don't know how to get its data using scrapy:

The HTML:

```html
<img width="768" height="1152" alt="Top com brilho - Preto - SENHORA | H&amp;M PT" class="Top com brilho - Preto - SENHORA | H&amp;M PT" srcset="//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality[79],source[/e4/e9/e4e96ab4841af66083ba521c17c1c18a8e300426.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_tops_vests],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[y],hmver[1]&amp;call=url[file:/product/main] 396w,
  //lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality[79],source[/e4/e9/e4e96ab4841af66083ba521c17c1c18a8e300426.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_tops_vests],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[w],hmver[1]&amp;call=url[file:/product/main] 564w, 
        //lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality[79],source[/e4/e9/e4e96ab4841af66083ba521c17c1c18a8e300426.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_tops_vests],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[s],hmver[1]&amp;call=url[file:/product/main] 657w, 
        //lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality[79],source[/e4/e9/e4e96ab4841af66083ba521c17c1c18a8e300426.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_tops_vests],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[1]&amp;call=url[file:/product/main] 820w" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 100vw, 50vw" src="//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=quality[79],source[/e4/e9/e4e96ab4841af66083ba521c17c1c18a8e300426.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_tops_vests],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[m],hmver[1]&amp;call=url[file:/product/main]">
```

Is there a way to get all the links or maybe make a list with all links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
self.img = response.xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/figure[1]/div/img/@srcset').get()
        self.img = self.img.split('\r')[0][2:]
        self.img, x = self.img.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if the website uses JSON or Javascript that will affect how scrapy handles the data. Click inspect elements in the website and try and to see if it selects all of the image links

```
//div[@class = 'product-detail-main-image-container']/img/@src
```